# Is It Possible To Generate HTML from PHP source outside of the browser?

Tags: php

If I have a .php file with dynamic content, how would I go about generating the html the browser sees, but outside of the browser? I.e. via the command line?

Comment: php yourscript.php

Comment: You can execute PHP scripts from the command line.

Comment: You can do it via the command line, using  `php yourfile.php`, or if you need to replicate for some reason the request through the webserver, you can use `curl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cURL` from the command line to send Http requests.

For example: `curl http://localhost:8080/index.php`

[Download it](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html)

[man curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html)